# XSLT getting a piece of xml to custommethod

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have a small question about XSLT, I've only recently started with xslt.
So the thing is I need to give with my custom method a piece of xml that matches the template, but the problem is, what I give is a string but it doenst have tags anymore:
so example if my xml looks like this:

```
<a>hi</a>
<a>bye</b>
```

I recieve only string that consists as this: "hi bye"
So I need to give instead of only the value/text of the node, but whole node with tags and attributes and elements etc etc.
My xslt looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="SpecialNode">
    <xsl:value-of select="CustomMethod:Handler(node()[*], @name)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

but whatsoever I tried (like `./node()` or `descendant::node()` or `*` and so on), I always get the string without xml tags :(
but I need to have something like this passed to my method in a string.

```
<a>hi</a><a>bye</a>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution. :)

Comment: You should invest in a keyboard with a shift key

Comment: That **implicit casting** depends entirely on the extension function and the API for extensions provided by your XSLT processor. Maybe, if you provide an explanation of your extension function, we might be able to give you an XSLT only implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the tag name, try

```
<xsl:template match="SpecialNode">
    <xsl:value-of select="CustomMethod:Handler(name(.))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

If you want the whole element, as well as the tag name, try

```
<xsl:template match="SpecialNode">
    <xsl:value-of select="CustomMethod:Handler(., name(.))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: no, i dont want only name, i need all, with tag names attributes and text as it is. Just when matchens i need to get that element with all his descendants. as normal xml piece. And a second example where  you say (., name(.)) is totaly not good, cuz as second parameter i give attribute and is is working ok, so ... and . only gives values of the node, but not the node and descendants itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
CustomMethod:Handler(.)
```

Comment: no, not wokring, as it gives only full string without the tag elements and attributes, but i need to get an xml piece as i asked in my queestion, see the result that i want to, but if i do your way i will have this as result: hibye

Answer (score 0):

Your XSLT stylesheet is processing a tree of nodes, and you want your external c# (?) code to see lexical serialized XML containing angle brackets. So the tree of nodes needs to be serialized into lexical XML somewhere along the line. That's not going to happen by magic as an implicit conversion done by a function call. It's probably best to let the C# code receive the data as nodes, and do the serialization from there - assuming the processing can't be node at the tree level.

Comment: i see :( so i cant then with xslt all the nodes that match the pattern, send them as piece of xml to the code :( but only the value of them